# Completeness of the category of boolean algebras

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Has the category of Boolean algebras all small limits? If so, is there a general result for showing that a category of algebras is complete such that one can show the category of Bolean algebras is complete as a particular case?

Comment: This is a pair of questions with two separate answers. Please pick one, and remove the other so both can be handled individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all categories that are monadic over $\mathbf{Set}$ are complete, because $\mathbf{Set}$ is.

More generally, the Eilenberg-Moore category of algebras for a monad on a category $\mathcal{C}$ has all limits that exist in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: You can have a look at the nLab article (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Moore+category#limits_and_colimits_in_em_categories) to start with.